# Programmatically switch 'local' IdentityProvider to Username via MS Graph API in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to script a B2C tenant and need to switch the **Local Accounts** Identity Provider to be Username based instead of email as per below picture.
MS Graph API returns an empty list for the path [GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{tenantid}/identityproviders](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/%7Btenantid%7D/identityproviders).
Is it possible to switch this programmatically?
I can migrate to the trustframework policy xml upload method if necessary but it seems like overkill.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scene you described should be for Azure AD B2C instead of Azure AD B2B.

It has a limitation in Microsoft Graph currently.

When we try to [List identityProviders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identityprovider-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), local account identity Provider won't be listed in the response. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/identityprovider?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

The supported types for identityProviders are:

- Microsoft
- Google
- Amazon
- LinkedIn
- Facebook
- GitHub
- Twitter
- Weibo
- QQ
- WeChat

So I'm afraid that we can't update the local account identity Provider via Microsoft Graph API.

If you are using user flow, I think the easiest way is to change it in Azure Portal.

If you can use custom policy, modify the configuration in custom policy is necessary.