# Configure Local IDP in Azure AD using API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

In Azure AD, we can configure the local IDP in the GUI by going into the "Azure AD B2C" service and then selecting "Identity Providers" and then selecting the "Local Account".

[sample image of configuring Local IDP in GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDkGy.png)

I'm trying to automate this process in my workflow, for which i need to configure this using an API.

I tried to get all the identity providers of my tenant using the below API, to get the ID of the identity provider, which I can use to configure it.

`GET /identity/identityProviders/availableProviderTypes`

All the identity provider type is listed in the response, except the local account.

Can someone help on how to configure the same using API ?

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, configuring local identity provider in Azure AD B2C via Microsoft Graph API is currently **not** supported.

When I ran **same query** as you to list all identity providers available in my Azure AD B2C directory via [***Graph Explorer***](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), local IDP is not present in **response** like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/identityProviders/availableProviderTypes
```

**Response:**
[image]

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(Edm.String)",
    "value": [
        "Microsoft",
        "Google",
        "Facebook",
        "Amazon",
        "LinkedIn",
        "Weibo",
        "QQ",
        "WeChat",
        "Twitter",
        "GitHub",
        "Apple",
        "AppleManaged",
        "OpenIdConnect"
    ]
}
```

I have below identity providers **configured** for my B2C tenant via Portal:

[image]

When I tried to list these **configured** identity providers via Graph API, I got only **`Google`** in my response like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/identity/identityProviders
```

**Response:**
[image]

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#identity/identityProviders",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.socialIdentityProvider",
            "id": "Google-OAUTH",
            "displayName": "Google",
            "identityProviderType": "Google",
            "clientId": "687526371346-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            "clientSecret": "******"
        }
    ]
}
```

AFAIK, configuring local identity provider in Azure AD B2C via **Azure Portal** is best possible way as of now.

You can also create a custom policy that includes a local account sign-up or sign-in user journey.

**Reference:**

[Switch to 'local' IdentityProvider via MS Graph API in Azure AD B2C - Stack Overflow by **Allen Wu**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61376134/programmatically-switch-local-identityprovider-to-username-via-ms-graph-api-in?rq=1)