# Azure MS Graph Rest API create local identity provider

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We have managed to programmatically  create an apple managed provider, a google provider and attached it successfully to a userflow in a b2c tenant using MS Graph Rest API documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/identitycontainer-post-identityproviders?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

However we would also like to create a local provider and attach it to the same userflow. We cannot see this option anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Listing available identity providers, we do not see a local provider.
We do not see any documentation on creating a local provider or how to enable a local provider on a userflow.

The closest documentation we have found is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-local?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Someone else posted this question 3 and a half years ago here:
[Programmatically switch 'local' IdentityProvider to Username via MS Graph API in Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61376134/programmatically-switch-local-identityprovider-to-username-via-ms-graph-api-in)

Am I to believe that after 3 and a half years this is still a limitation of MS Graph? If this is a case, can I raise this as an issue on github? Anyone know which github project I would raise this on?